# How to change the label and grid line position on a timeseries chart in Chart.js 3?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm upgrading from Chart.js 2 to 3 and encountering problems with my time chart.
Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/58L42w3u/

(I obviously have to put some code in here too:)

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var data = [{"x":"2021-06-01","t":null,"o":null}/* more in JsFiddle */];
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    datasets: [
      {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(50,38,113,0.4)',
        barPercentage: 1.0,
        categoryPercentage: 1.0,
        data: data,
        label: 'Total',
        parsing: {
          yAxisKey: 't',
        },
      },
      {
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(59,191,69,0.4)',
        barPercentage: 1.0,
        categoryPercentage: 1.0,
        data: data,
        label: 'Occupied',
        parsing: {
          yAxisKey: 'o',
        },
      },
    ]
  },
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    responsive: true,
    scales: {
      x: {
        bounds: 'data',
        stacked: true,
        ticks: {
          autoSkip: false,
        },
        time: {
          displayFormats: {
            month: 'MMM YY',
          },
          unit: 'month'
        },
        type: 'timeseries'
      },
      y: {
        beginAtZero: true,
      },
    },
  }
});
```

As you can see, the data holds every day from 2021-06-01 to 2021-10-30.
Currently, the x-axis grid lines are displayed in the center of a month and the x-axis labels at the start of a month. I'd like the exact opposite:
The grid line should be before every first of a month and the labels between those lines. I just cannot find a way to manage that.

Comment: Do you have any picture of expected result?

Comment: I have a jsfiddle with Chart.js 2 here: https://jsfiddle.net/2qzm74e9/ The grid lines are correct here. But I wasn't able to center the labels there as well. But the grid lines are the more important problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for `offset: false`?

```
options: {
  scales: {
    x: {        
      grid: {
        offset: false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`false` should be the default value according to the docs, but maybe `type: 'timeseries'` changes this.

Example:

[image: Example]

Comment: Oh man! I've tried that one, but as `false` is the default value, I've set it only to `true`. But where does that gap between the chart grid line and the y-axis grid line from "Jun 21" come from? In other words: The bars of the 2021-07-01 are ON the y-axis grid line and not right of it.

Comment: I honestly don't know :(